# Where to set Sentry's setUser in Next.js app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, sentry

I have been trying to set user data into Sentry's scope globally, so every time there's an error or event, user info is passed to it.

My app is built in Next.js, so naturally I added the config as it is in Sentry's documentation for Next.js.

I haven't got the idea on where to add the Sentry.setUser({id: user.Id}) method in order for it to set the user globally.

So far I have added it to the Sentry's _error.js file, inside the getInitialProps method:

```
import NextErrorComponent from 'next/error';

import * as Sentry from '@sentry/nextjs';
import { getUser } from '../lib/session';

const MyError = ({ statusCode, hasGetInitialPropsRun, err }) => {
    if (!hasGetInitialPropsRun && err) {
        Sentry.captureException(err);
    }

    return <NextErrorComponent statusCode={statusCode} />;
};

MyError.getInitialProps = async (context) => {
    const errorInitialProps = await NextErrorComponent.getInitialProps(context);

    const { req, res, err, asPath } = context;

    errorInitialProps.hasGetInitialPropsRun = true;

    const user = await getUser(req, res);

    // Set user information
    if (user) {
        console.log('Setting user');
        Sentry.setUser({ id: user.Id });
    }
    else {
        console.log('Removing user');
        Sentry.configureScope(scope => scope.setUser(null));
    }

    if (res?.statusCode === 404) {
        return errorInitialProps;
    }


    if (err) {
        Sentry.captureException(err);

        await Sentry.flush(2000);

        return errorInitialProps;
    }

    Sentry.captureException(
        new Error(`_error.js getInitialProps missing data at path: ${asPath}`),
    );
    await Sentry.flush(2000);

    return errorInitialProps;
};

export default MyError;
```

But when trying to log errors, the user info doesn't show in Sentry, only the default user ip:

[image]

I have also tried setting the user after successful login, and still nothing..

Help is appreciated!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if this is the right way, but the above solutions didn't work for me. So I tried calling setUser inside `_app.tsx`.

```js
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { setUser } from "@sentry/nextjs";
import { UserProvider, useUser } from "@auth0/nextjs-auth0";
import type { AppProps } from "next/app";

function SentryUserManager() {
  const { user } = useUser();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (user) {
      setUser({
        email: user.email ?? undefined,
        username: user.name ?? undefined,
      });
    } else {
      setUser(null);
    }
  }, [user]);
  return null;
}

export default function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  return (
    <UserProvider>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
      <SentryUserManager />
    </UserProvider>
  );
}
```

Still not sure why this worked for me and the other solutions didn't, but figured it was worth sharing.

Comment: This worked!! The only problem is that for some reason Sentry only sends the user Id, and not the other user properties. I ended up setting them with the setTags method, which shouldn't be ideal. I haven't found helpful information about the issue.

Comment: Hmm thats odd, in our case sentry sends the email and username. The documentation could definitely have better guidance on where to make this call.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using the [callback handler](https://auth0.github.io/nextjs-auth0/modules/handlers_callback.html#modify-the-session-after-login) to set your Sentry user context.

```
import { handleAuth, handleLogin, handleCallback } from "@auth0/nextjs-auth0";
import * as Sentry from "@sentry/nextjs";
import { NextApiHandler } from "next";

const afterCallback = (_req, _res, session, _state) => {
  Sentry.setUser({
    id: session.user.sub,
    email: session.user.email,
    username: session.user.nickname,
    name: session.user.name,
    avatar: session.user.picture,
  });
  return session;
};

const handler: NextApiHandler = handleAuth({
  async login(req, res) {
    await handleLogin(req, res, {
      returnTo: "/dashboard",
    });
  },
  async callback(req, res) {
    try {
      await handleCallback(req, res, { afterCallback });
    } catch (error) {
      res.status(error.status || 500).end(error.message);
    }
  },
});

export default Sentry.withSentry(handler);
```

Comment: I don't think this works since `afterCallback` only gets called 1 time after the user gets logged in and since its serverless the next request isn't going to have this context. At least on the server side of a Next.js app.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the user in Sentry right after successful login

```
const handleLogin = {
  try {
    const res = await axios.post("/login", {"john@example.com", "password"})
    if (res && res?.data) {
      // Do other stuff
      Sentry.setUser({ email: "john@example.com" });
    }
  }
}
```

Additionaly you can clear the user while logging out

```
const handleLogout = {
  // Do othe stuff
  Sentry.configureScope(scope => scope.setUser(null));
}
```

Comment: Already tried that and nothing.. still getting only the IP

Comment: How about axios interceptors ?